# How to use gear motor 9 with Arduino

Tags: arduino, motor

I am new to robotics. I want to make a robot using Arduino Uno R3. I need to use Gear Motor 9 for that [here is the link](https://solarbotics.com/product/gm9/).

The problem is that motor needs 50mA current. But arduino only outputs only 40mA current.

I want to supply the motors with another power source and use a switch to connect both the circuits. Can you please tell me what type of switch I can use.

Thanks in Advance. 
P.S. Sorry if I used any wrong technical terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This motor is based on a simple DC motor. Don't be mistaken, it will draw much more than 50ma when running with even small load, just look at it's datasheet. In case you want to control the motor's speed, you will need some kind of DC motor driver, which you could build (look up H-bridge) or buy, and than use PWM technique to control it. In case you want just to turn it on and off, the simplest solution would be a relay controlled by arduino's digital output and connected in series with your additional power supply and the motor.